when i click submit in the page the info i login in the page doesn't insert in the database i am using next js and vercel
I have been working in this code for almost three days I'm really in my end wits
when i write the code and sign the form data in code sheet and save it work but when i do it like this it doesn't
this the code for the frontend page
the database im using is https://vercel.com/ postgressql
the code path ra\app\testtt\page.tsx
'use client'

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { sql, QueryResult, QueryResultRow } from '@vercel/postgres';

function UserForm({ username, email, password, user_type }: { username: string, email: string, password: string, user_type: string }): React.ReactNode {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    username: '',
    email: '',
    password: '',
    user_type: 't',
  });

  const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLSelectElement>) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setFormData({ ...formData, [name]: value });
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    try {
      const result: QueryResult<QueryResultRow> = await sql<QueryResultRow>`
        INSERT INTO users (username, email, password, user_type)
        VALUES (${username}, ${email}, ${password}, ${user_type})
        RETURNING *;`;
      
      console.log('Data inserted successfully:', result);
      // You can handle success or failure here
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error inserting data:', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label htmlFor="username">Username:</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          id="username"
          name="username"
          value={formData.username}
          onChange={handleChange}
          required
        />
  
        <label htmlFor="email">Email:</label>
        <input
          type="email"
          id="email"
          name="email"
          value={formData.email}
          onChange={handleChange}
          required
        />
  
        <label htmlFor="password">Password:</label>
        <input
          type="password"
          id="password"
          name="password"
          value={formData.password}
          onChange={handleChange}
          required
        />
  
        <label htmlFor="user_type">User Type:</label>
        <select
          id="user_type"
          name="user_type"
          value={formData.user_type}
          onChange={handleChange}
        >
          <option value="t">t</option>
          <option value="g">g</option>
          <option value="business_owner">Business Owner</option>
        </select>
  
        <button type="submit">Create User</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
export default UserForm;


i tried every solution
i think the problem in the handleSubmit

I am not seeing anywhere that you commit the transaction. So unless await sql is using autocommit of some sort the INSERT will not persist pass the session.
